# Send Billing Country name to Woocommerce admin Email Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, custom-fields, country

**From function.php file.**

```
<?php 
        add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'woocommerce_add_billing_address_to_admin_emails', 15, 2 ); 
         ?>
```

Comment: Are you asking a question or giving answer?

Comment: @Frits i think you got a wrong person tagged on your answer. :)

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli oh lawd sorry 0_o fixing it now!

Comment: Hi Mujahith iahi - welcome to Stack Overflow. This forum follows a Question and Answer format. Your post seems to be an answer to a question that wasn't asked. You can, if needed, post your question first, and then post your answer, but I would suggest first seeing if the question has already been asked (which is most likely) and then posting your answer to that question if your solution is unique compared to the other answers on that same question. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to Your **function.php** file. :-)

```
<?php 
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'woocommerce_add_billing_address_to_admin_emails', 15, 2 ); 
function woocommerce_add_billing_address_to_admin_emails( $order, $is_admin_email ) { 
    if ( $is_admin_email ) { 
        echo '<div style="width:100%; background-color: #f2f2f2;">
            <p style="padding: 15px;margin: 15px 0;">Billing Country: <strong>'.WC()->countries->countries[ $order->billing_country ].'</strong></p>
            </div>';
    } 
} ?>
```